# Flashing screen during videos and games

Tags: 12.10, graphics

I recently switched from Vista to Ubuntu 12.10 on my HP laptop and I've been having issues with my graphics. Everything is  fine till I watch a video/play a game or (sometimes) when I visit the software centre. At that point large portions of the screen start flashing and everything gets rather slow. I'm looking for a way to remedy this.

For reference I'm using Firefox and I'm unsure what my video card is because it's listed as unknown when I check my system settings.

Answer (score 1):

Problem has been fixed. For the references of others it was fixed when I took the bottom off my laptop and cleared it with a compressed air duster. Overheating may have been the problem.